# Shelter of or Shelter from?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

“Since her brother had left, she’d felt a bit unguarded out there. The library was a little **shelter of** civilisation.”

The Midnight Library
Matt Haig
What is “shelter of civilization” meaning in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the shelter *of* civilization was giving her shelter *from* the difficulties, protecting her from the *un*civilized parts of the world. Similar to seeking shelter of a doorway or portico in the rain. Despite this author's sensible choice the more typical use is *from*. We seek shelter from the storm or from the terrible exterior elements such as they are.

Comment: I just wanted to highlight the important part, in case there's confusion: **Yes**, the author chose "**of**" and meant it, and this means that the library "is" civilisation. This is like saying "a shelter of sticks": we're describing the nature of the shelter.